# End user providing a favicon to a website via javascript extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, favicon, head

**Want:** A website which I don't control to display a favicon, so that I can find it easily in my bookmark toolbar.

**Problem:** The web developer forgot to link the favicon on the "elearning" subdomain

**Attempted Reconciliation:** Created this javascript extension; run through Scriptish 0.1.8 on Firefox Nightly 21.0a1 (2013-01-14)

```
// ==UserScript==
// @id             120398
// @name           AngelIco
// @version        1.0
// @namespace      
// @author         
// @description    
// @include        https://elearning.fgcu.edu/default.asp
// @run-at         document-start
// @require        http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.6/jquery.js
// ==/UserScript==
$('head').append("<link rel=\"shortcut icon\" href=\"//fgcu.edu/favicon.ico\"/>");
$('head').append("<script>alert(\"Oh, it worked!!!!!\")</script>");
```

**Expected behavior of script:** Will insert a link to the favicon, and load it.

**Actual behavior of script:** Firebug indicates that the link to the favicon was successfully inserted, and alerts "Oh, it worked!!!!!", but a favicon is not actually displayed.

**Attempted debugging:**

1. Played with when the script loads

   ```
   //@run-at document-start //document-idle //document-end
   ```
2. Tried loading the favicon from my local hard drive

   ```
   $('head').append("<link rel=\"shortcut icon\" href=\"file:///C:/Users/Tyler/Desktop/favicon.ico\"/>");
   ```

**Please respond with either:** (in order of preference)

1. A fix for my user script.
2. An alternate way to achieve what I want.
3. A vague hint as to what I have to do to make this work, followed by this winking face ";-)"
4. An insult.
5. No response.

Comment: 4) your father smells of elderberries? otherwise...did you check the 'page info' (tools menu) window in FF to see if the icon shows up as a resource on the page? just having your alert show up doesn't mean FF actually tried to reach out to the server to load that .ico file.

Comment: Have you tried adding http:// to the `<link>`?

Comment: Perhaps the favicon is checked by the browser *before* any javascript is run. I could be wrong though, I haven't researched it.

Comment: _This_ is how you ask a question on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the run-at line to

```
//@run-at document-end
```

and going off of TryingToImprove's suggestion worked. 
you can see in the

```
//@include
```

line that I'm running the script on a secured page. My link must have pointed to "https://" instead of "http://", and the icon file did not exist there. Not sure why my local reference didn't work; I went back and tested it again after changing the //@run-at line, and the local reference still didn't work. Beats me.